# Is there a way to use a block comment on a section that's already commented?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, comments

I know you can comment out a whole section of code like so:

```
/*
line of code
line of code
line of code
*/
```

But if you already have a /* ... */ section in the code that you are trying to comment, then the */ end of a comment block will close the "greater" comment block I am trying to create.

Example:

```
/* wanting to comment this big section out
line of code
line of code
line of code
line of code
line of code
line of code
/* this section was already commented out before
line of code
line of code
line of code
*/ this section was already commented out before
line of code
line of code
line of code
line of code
line of code
*/ this last part doesn't get commented out, because the comment stops at previous */
```

Obviously this isn't a huge big deal, it is not stopping me from getting an app to work properly, but I'm just wondering if there might be some way of commenting out a larger section of code, even if there are already comment blocks in that code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Highlight the code you want commented out and press "Command" + "/"

Comment: What a great shortcut! Thanks!  =)

Answer (score 4):

To avoid such a situation, always use `//` for commenting and use Xcode shortcut to comment a block of code.

The shortcut is `cmd + /`

Comment: Thank you! Shortcuts are the best. =)

Answer (score 0):

I'd frown if I saw it in code, but you can do

```
#if 0

...code...

#endif
```